# Automate to open a page and take screenshots

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

i am trying to make a program in python that opens a link and scrolls through the page to take screenshots. This screenshots will then be analyzed with OCR to recognize the text. My program opens the page takes a screenshot and then scrolls and takes onother screenshot until it reaches the end. The problem is i cant make it scroll exactly my screen height and as a result a few lines of text appear in 2 screenshots(the last few lines in the first screenshot and the first lines in the second screenshot).
This is my code and it scrolls a little more than my screen height so i miss some text:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# open the web page
driver.get("https://www.stoiximan.gr/sport/basket/")

# wait for the page to load completely
time.sleep(5)

# maximize the window
driver.maximize_window()

# wait for a few seconds
time.sleep(2)


# XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
# get the height of the browser window
window_height = driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight")
# XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX


print(window_height)

# set the initial scroll position to 0
scroll_position = 0

# loop until the end of the page is reached
while True:
    # take a screenshot of the current page
    screenshot_name = f"screenshot_{scroll_position}.png"
    driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_name)
    

    # XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    # scroll down by half of the window height
    scroll_position += window_height
    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {scroll_position});")
    # XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX


    # wait for a few seconds
    time.sleep(2)
    
    # check if the end of the page is reached
    if scroll_position >= driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"):
        break

# close the browser
driver.quit()
```

i have also tried to find the screen height with tkinter but it still scrolls more than my screen height:
import tkinter as tk

```
import tkinter as tk

# create a new root window
root = tk.Tk()

# get the height of the screen
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

# print the screen height
print(f"Screen height: {screen_height} pixels")

# destroy the root window
root.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

In headless mode you can get a single screenshot of the whole page, that's because headless browser is not limited by your screen resolution. So you can do the following

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.stoiximan.gr/sport/basket/')

full_width  = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
full_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
driver.set_window_size(full_width, full_height)
driver.save_screenshot('full_page.png')
```